# How do I create a unique PHP variable for each value in an array?

Tags: php, jquery

I currently have the following, which makes an array of all values in the `column ProblemNameTest` of the MYSQL database and assigns a variable to the first one. Ex: If ProblemNameTest has Problem1, Problem2, and Problem3 as entries, it will assign $selector1 to ProblemName1.

```
<?php
   $data5 = $db->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ProblemNameTest ORDER BY rand()) as ProblemNameTest FROM (SELECT ProblemNameTest FROM answers WHERE user_id=$id AND ProblemNameTest LIKE 's%') AS ProblemNameTest")->fetch_assoc();
$selector= $data5['ProblemNameTest'];
$selector1=str_word_count($selector, 1);
?>
```

I also have the following JQuery, which assigns the class `Active` to any itme with a class equal to that first word in the array. `Active` has unique CSS properties. Ex: If a div has class=`ProblemName1' it will also have the class`Active` assigned, so those unique CSS properties will be assigned to this div.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.<?php echo $selector1; ?>').addClass("Active"); 
});
</script>
```

How could I modify this, so that the class `Active` is assigned to classes equal to anything within the array. I realize that I could just change the `1` in the line `$selector1=str_word_count($selector, 1);` but I want this to be self-running, so that if there are 500 values in the array, I don't have to copy and paste that 500 times.

In general terms, I'm thinking it needs to look something like the following, but I'm not sure how to execute it

```
<?php
.....
    $selector[*incremental increase from 1*]=str_word_count($selector, [*incremental increase from 1*]);
    ?> 

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.<?php echo $selector[*all of the variables generated above*]; ?>').addClass("Active"); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Concatenate the unique number(id) to each variable.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Thanks for your response. Could you give me some pointers as to how I can do that with my code? My knowledge of PHP is limited to a few site's courses, so I'm not sure how I would do what you suggested. My skills are now left to  the mercy of what I can learn from others on the Internet haha.

Comment: That's OK. But what about your query? You do multi step like query and fetch. Is you query return multiple rows??

Comment: You can check this example: https://3v4l.org/J8urP

Comment: That's a great suggestion. Thanks, @FrayneKonok. The query return is for multiple rows.